# Get Font from resources in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uifont

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

can I set font file into resources of program and after that use this font in iPhone?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about a custom font or one that is already available in the device?

Comment: As I know some fonts don't available in ios 3.0 and I need some solution of this problem..

Comment: See this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application).

Comment: Thanks it's really great example!