# How to Set Custom Font to UILabel in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fonts

I want to set the custom font to UILabel in storyboard. I have .ttf file of font. I searched about it on google, everybody is setting the font programmatically.

Comment: you have to set custom font programmatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [uilabel custom font?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449123/uilabel-custom-font)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the control (label) and add **User Defined Runtime Attribute** (**Key Path** set to **fontName** , **Type** set to **String** and **Value** set to the name of your custom font).

**Note:**

Make sure that you've added the font to the project - [tutorial](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/06/adding-non-standard-fonts-to-ios5-apps/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. Partially solved my problem. I referred this link to solve my problem. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090745/custom-font-in-a-storyboard/15155081#15155081

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that this is a new feature added to the Interface Builder in Xcode 6 as documented [here](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_6_gl2i5q/xcode_6__beta_6_release_notes.pdf)

Comment: @pawan you need to be logged into developer.apple.com with your developer account

Answer (score 1):

Connect Your IBOutlet to Label and you can set like this,

```
lblHeading.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ApexNew-Bold" size:17];

in the above code ApexNew-Bold is custom font and you need to add it in Plistfile.
```

[image]

Comment: This will work fine. I wanted to do this in storyboard.