# Custom Font iOS doesn't showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to install my custom font for my app. I alreayd donde this many of times, but with this font I don't know why it doesn't work

Note: My info.plist its correct with the file Geometry Soft Pro.ttf

Font file:
Geometry Soft Pro.ttf

I already try the code with:

- Geometry Soft Pro
- GeometrySoftPro
- GeometrySoftPro-BoldN
- GeometrySoftPro-Bold N
- Geometry Soft Pro-Bold N
- Geometry Soft Pro Bold N

My code:

```
[nivel.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Geometry Soft Pro" size:42]];
```

Font info:

[image]

Here is my info.plist
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you added the font to project (and it's been copied to the target)? Also, have you added it to your app .plist?

Comment: Yes my font name its the same that the in the plist Geometry Soft Pro.ttf and I'm sure its on the project. And also in "Copy Bundle Resources"

Comment: Is the font family listed in `+[UIFont familyNames]`?

Comment: No I want my own custom font @一二三

Comment: Your custom font should be in that array if it is being loaded correctly.

Comment: @一二三 Hi men, I check it again and the font it's in that array "Geometry Soft Pro,"

Comment: What's the output of `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Geometry Soft Pro"]`?

Comment: @一二三 I just remove whitespaces in the font file and it works

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Fonts Xcode 4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432373/custom-fonts-xcode-4-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remove the white spaces from the font file name. And change name in info.plist file. Thats all.  Happy Coding :)

Comment: Remove spaces from font file name. Then add name without spaces in info.plist. N try once again.. :P

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but none of this helped me, i change the **Fonts provided by application** with **UIAppFonts** and it works , even if the .ttf file name is different from the font name.

Answer (score 0):

Check if font file is added in "Copy bundle resources" under project settings-> Build phases. 
Also install the font in MAC & use the same name (with / without spaces in between) in your iOS code. Let me know if it works for you.