# Custom font style issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, fonts

I'm facing a problem with the changing the font style of label. But I don't understand how it can be.
I want to use "Helvetica Neue LT Pro 33 thin extended" style. And I've install it but when I've used like this

```
self.saveButton_label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Saved", nil);
self.saveButton_label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue LT Pro 33 Thin Extended" size: 12.5];
```

It does not work.but when I've tried like this

```
self.saveButton_label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Saved", nil);
self.saveButton_label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue LT Pro" size: 12.5];
```

it works but the problem was that It set the style "Helvetica Neue LT Pro 73 Bold Extended"
And I have installed different style of Helvetica Neue 
[image]

please answer if anybody know that how can I use "Helvetica Neue LT Pro 33 thin Extended" thanks in advance...

Comment: You need hyphen in "Helvetica Neue LT Pro 33-Thin Extended"; possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907100/issues-with-setting-some-different-font-for-uilabel. Call `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica Neue LT Pro"]` to see the name the system wants from you

Comment: To make sure what fonts (together with its names) that your application provides, you have to populate it. See this link http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/ on how to do this

Comment: thanks to all of you but I just want family name of "Helvetica Neue LT Pro 33 thin extended".

Answer (score 0):

Fonts have programmatic names that differ from what you see in the Fonts app. The family is followed by a hyphen, then the style. For best results, call

`NSArray *fontFamilyNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica Neue LT Pro"]`

and log what you get back to see just how the strings look (or inspect in debugger).
You'll probably need a hyphen in "Helvetica Neue LT Pro 33-Thin Extended". Once you get the name just right, things should work fine. See also [Issues with setting some different font for UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907100/issues-with-setting-some-different-font-for-uilabel) for an instance of this issue.

Comment: Hey, I've done but still I cannot find "Helvetica Neue LT Pro 33 Thin Extended" font style.