# Why loading a font in an iPhone application only work for iOS >= 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, fonts, uibutton

I'm trying to load a font into an application. I think I'm doing it well. But it doesn't work on iOS < 5.0.

I'm included the font files as resources (using otf files), add them to UIAppFonts array and testing the fonts on buttons. Like this:

In Info.plist:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>FrutigerNextPro-Medium.otf</string>
        <string>FrutigerNextPro-MediumIta.otf</string>
        <string>FrutigerNextPro-Light.otf</string>
        <string>FrutigerNextPro-LightIta.otf</string>
    </array>
```

Them in the buttons like this:

```
btt_01.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FrutigerNextPro-Medium" size:20];
btt_02.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FrutigerNextPro-MediumIta" size:20];
btt_03.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FrutigerNextPro-Light" size:20];
btt_04.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FrutigerNextPro-LightIta" size:20];
```

The problem is that *FrutigerNextPro-Medium* and *FrutigerNextPro-MediumIta* are only loaded in devices and simulator using iOS >= 5.0.
In devices and simulator with iOS < 5.0 it doesn't loads the font, I think it loads *FrutigerNextPro-Light*

and When I Log like this:

```
for (NSString *family in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:family]);
}
```

I get the font available in any platform:

```
 (
    "FrutigerNextPro-MediumIta",
    "FrutigerNextPro-LightIta",
    "FrutigerNextPro-Medium",
    "FrutigerNextPro-Light"
)
```

I get the font available in any platform.

Can someone help me trying to understand what's going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I believe OTF fonts were not officially supported in earlier versions of iOS. You can probably use a tool to convert these fonts to TTF.

Comment: if it so why FrutigerNextPro-Light is loaded and FrutigerNextPro-Medium not?? both are in otf format.. don't understand what is happening..

Comment: Already converted all fonts to ttf, still having the same issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it's a limitation,  that only 2 variants of a single font face is supported.

Check this: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/59855-ipad-custom-font-issue.html

But still with no solution.. still unable to load *FrutigerNextPro-Medium* in iOS < 5.0..
I will try to convert the font..

**EDIT:**
I converted all fonts to ttf, but don't believe that was the solution.

What I did was (like in the forum says) **change the Font Family Name**.

Then I realize that is true, it's an issue, can't have 2 variants of a single font family.

Now its working.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add custom font for older version of iOS then use this approch [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)