# Xcode: Using custom fonts inside Dynamic framework

Tags: swift, ios8, frameworks

I added custom font to a framework. I followed all the steps, but it doesn't work.

I am able to set the font in Interface Builder, but when I build the project it doesn't show this font on the simulator/device.

Comment: Did you try out the method in my answer?  I've been using it in a few apps that use custom fonts bundled with a dynamic framework, without needing to add the fonts to the main project.

Comment: For people looking into the top answers, understand that `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` shouldn't be the class to use, they even tell you not to use it in its own doc. Use `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL` based answers at the bottom

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'm here a bit late, but I took PetahChristian's solution and created a Swift version in the form of an extension.  This is working for me.  I've found that when you try to get a font using a font name and a size using the regular way that it always looks in the main bundle for the font file, and there's no method that takes a bundle identifier as a parameter.  It would be nice if Apple would make one.

**Swift:**

```
public extension UIFont {

    public static func jbs_registerFont(withFilenameString filenameString: String, bundle: Bundle) {

        guard let pathForResourceString = bundle.path(forResource: filenameString, ofType: nil) else {
            print("UIFont+:  Failed to register font - path for resource not found.")
            return
        }

        guard let fontData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathForResourceString) else {
            print("UIFont+:  Failed to register font - font data could not be loaded.")
            return
        }

        guard let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: fontData) else {
            print("UIFont+:  Failed to register font - data provider could not be loaded.")
            return
        }

        guard let font = CGFont(dataProvider) else {
            print("UIFont+:  Failed to register font - font could not be loaded.")
            return
        }

        var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
        if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &errorRef) == false) {
            print("UIFont+:  Failed to register font - register graphics font failed - this font may have already been registered in the main bundle.")
        }
    }

}
```

Usage Example:

```
UIFont.jbs_registerFont(
    withFilenameString: "Boogaloo-Regular.ttf",
    bundle: Bundle(identifier: "com.JBS.JBSFramework")!
)
```

Comment: Instead of using `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont ` you should use `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL`, and let the loading the contents of the file into memory be handled by the system.

Comment: Indeed this answer is outdated. `...RegisterFontsForURL` and `...RegisterFontURLs` are available and SHOULD be used (as specified in the DOC of `...GraphicsFont`). Please upvote the answers at the bottom mentioning it.

Answer (score 19):

The following solution allows you to load all fonts with a certain extension automatically:

```
static func registerFonts() {
    let fonts = Bundle(for: 
OrientationMonitor.self).urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "ttf", subdirectory: nil)
    fonts?.forEach({ url in
        CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(url as CFURL, .process, nil)
    })
}
```

Make sure to replace `OrientationMonitor` with a class existing in your framework.

Comment: I went with your approach of explicitly registering everything, as it appears (Xcode 12) that any fonts not in the Main.storyboard weren't getting registered (even though I was doing everything else right...). My minor simplification:  `let fonts = Bundle.main.urls(...)`

Comment: You might even want to use the `CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs(...)` method to remove the `forEach`

Comment: This one works perfectly fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 15):

Here's my version of John's answer, showing how to call the function if you have lots of fonts

```
import Foundation

extension UIFont {

    @nonobjc static var loadAllFontsDO: dispatch_once_t = 0

    class func initialsAvatarFont() -> UIFont {
        loadAllFonts()
        if let retval = UIFont(name: "MyFontName", size: kInitialsAvatarFontSize) {
            return retval;
        } else {
            return UIFont.systemFontOfSize(kInitialsAvatarFontSize)
        }
    }

    class func loadAllFonts() {
        dispatch_once(&loadAllFontsDO) { () -> Void in
            registerFontWithFilenameString("thefontfilename.ttf", bundleIdentifierString: "nameOfResourceBundleAlongsideTheFrameworkBundle")
            // Add more font files here as required
        }
    }

    static func registerFontWithFilenameString(filenameString: String, bundleIdentifierString: String) {
        let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(forClass: AnyClassInYourFramework.self)
        let resourceBundleURL = frameworkBundle.URLForResource(bundleIdentifierString, withExtension: "bundle")
        if let bundle = NSBundle(URL: resourceBundleURL!) {
            let pathForResourceString = bundle.pathForResource(filenameString, ofType: nil)
            let fontData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathForResourceString!)
            let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(fontData)
            let fontRef = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(dataProvider)
            var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil

            if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef!, &errorRef) == false) {
                NSLog("Failed to register font - register graphics font failed - this font may have already been registered in the main bundle.")
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Failed to register font - bundle identifier invalid.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this nice solution. One question when passing the bundleIdentifierString, what is meant by "nameOfResourceBundleAlongsideTheFrameworkBundle"? Can you provide an example. Appreciate it! Thanks

Comment: @DaisyR. It's been a long time since I wrote this, but: this solution is for when you are building a framework and a resource bundle alongside it. In other words you are giving some other developer 2 files, `foo.framework` and `foo.bundle`. The nameOfResourceBundle... refers to `foo.bundle`

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately did this not work in my case and in Swift 3 dispatch_once does not exist, but probably with an extension it's doable. I don't understand the need for this block though for loading fonts. I know this is the solution for when you are building a framework, this is how I got to this post :)

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4**:

This is maybe an old thread but has updated @xaphod for swift 4 as all static and global variables are lazily initialised using dispatch_once.

```
extension UIFont {

// load framework font in application
public static let loadAllFonts: () = {
    registerFontWith(filenameString: "SanFranciscoText-Regular.otf", bundleIdentifierString: "Fonts")
    registerFontWith(filenameString: "SanFranciscoText-Medium.otf", bundleIdentifierString: "Fonts")
    registerFontWith(filenameString: "SanFranciscoText-Semibold.otf", bundleIdentifierString: "Fonts")
    registerFontWith(filenameString: "SanFranciscoText-Bold.otf", bundleIdentifierString: "Fonts")
    registerFontWith(filenameString: "SanFranciscoText-LightItalic.otf", bundleIdentifierString: "Fonts")
}()

//MARK: - Make custom font bundle register to framework
static func registerFontWith(filenameString: String, bundleIdentifierString: String) {
    let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: MSAlertController.self)
    let resourceBundleURL = frameworkBundle.url(forResource: bundleIdentifierString, withExtension: "bundle")
    if let url = resourceBundleURL, let bundle = Bundle(url: url) {
        let pathForResourceString = bundle.path(forResource: filenameString, ofType: nil)
        if let fontData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathForResourceString!), let dataProvider = CGDataProvider.init(data: fontData) {
            let fontRef = CGFont.init(dataProvider)
            var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
            if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef!, &errorRef) == false) {
                print("Failed to register font - register graphics font failed - this font may have already been registered in the main bundle.")
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Failed to register font - bundle identifier invalid.")
    }
}
}
```

Then you can call `UIFont.loadAllfont` inside the appDelegate

Answer (score 10):

I made a mix of different answers in **Swift 4.2** so props to the guys who came up with it!

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension UIFont {

    private class MyDummyClass {}

    static func loadFontWith(name: String) {
        let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: MyDummyClass.self)
        let pathForResourceString = frameworkBundle.path(forResource: name, ofType: "ttf")
        let fontData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathForResourceString!)
        let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: fontData!)
        let fontRef = CGFont(dataProvider!)
        var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil

        if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef!, &errorRef) == false) {
            NSLog("Failed to register font - register graphics font failed - this font may have already been registered in the main bundle.")
        }
    }

    public static let loadMyFonts: () = {
        loadFontWith(name: "Exo-Black")
        loadFontWith(name: "Exo-Bold")
        loadFontWith(name: "Exo-Regular")    
    }()
}
```

And then call in Appdelegate

```
UIFont.loadMyFonts
```

Comment: From the documentation for `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(_:_:)`
> Fonts that are backed by files should be registered using `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(_:_:_:).`
Since this example is loading a font from a file, I assume it's not the intended way to to use this API.

Answer (score 8):

You can load and use bundled custom fonts from your dynamic framework by implementing the +`load` method in your framework.

In the `load` method, you locate the fonts in the bundle, then register them.  This makes them available to the app, without having to specify them in the main project.

```
+ (void)load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
     dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        // Dynamically load bundled custom fonts

        [self bible_loadFontWithName:kBIBLECustomFontBoldName];
        [self bible_loadFontWithName:kBIBLECustomFontBoldItalicName];
        [self bible_loadFontWithName:kBIBLECustomFontItalicName];
        [self bible_loadFontWithName:kBIBLECustomFontRegularName];
    });
}

+ (void)bible_loadFontWithName:(NSString *)fontName
{
     NSString *fontPath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[BIBLE class]] pathForResource:fontName ofType:@"otf"];
     NSData *fontData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fontPath];

     CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)fontData);

     if (provider)
     {
        CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);

         if (font)
         {
             CFErrorRef error = NULL;
             if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error) == NO)
             {
                 CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
                 NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
                 CFRelease(errorDescription);
             }

             CFRelease(font);
        }

        CFRelease(provider);
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll need `#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>` to be able to use `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont `

Comment: Thank you kind sir

Answer (score 8):

I've created an extension on `UIFont` that will register all fonts (of a given type) that are found in a bundle. Note that since this registers the fonts, there is no need to include the 'Fonts provided by application' in the framework's Info.plist.

```
extension UIFont {

    private static var fontsRegistered: Bool = false

    static func registerFontsIfNeeded() {
        guard
            !fontsRegistered,
            let fontURLs = someBundle?.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "otf", subdirectory: nil)
        else { return }

        fontURLs.forEach({ CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL($0 as CFURL, .process, nil) })
        fontsRegistered = true
    }
}
```

then just make sure to call `registerFontsIfNeeded()` before you attempt to create an instance of your custom font. i.e

```
...
registerFontsIfNeeded()

let myCustomFont = UIFont(name: "My-Custom-Font-Name", size: 20)
...
```

Comment: It might not need a forEach by using the `...RegisterFontURLs` function instead no? Good answer anyway 

Answer (score 7):

Found a really easy and readable way to register font, which is not mentioned here:

```
func registerFont(with fontName: String) {
    guard let url = Bundle(for: BundleToken.self).url(forResource: fontName, withExtension: nil),
        CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(url as CFURL, .process, nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to register font: \(font.fileName)")
    }
}

private final class BundleToken {}
```

Comment: Thank you! I found this API works with `UIFontPickerViewController` whereas fonts registered with `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont ` do not appear in the list for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to do this with Swift 4, given that you can include resources directly in a framework bundle now:

`Typography.swift` (in my framework)

```
import Foundation

private class MyDummyClass {}

func loadFontWith(name: String) {
  let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: MyDummyClass.self)
  let pathForResourceString = frameworkBundle.path(forResource: name, ofType: "otf")
  let fontData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathForResourceString!)
  let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: fontData!)
  let fontRef = CGFont(dataProvider!)
  var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil

  if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef!, &errorRef) == false) {
    NSLog("Failed to register font - register graphics font failed - this font may have already been registered in the main bundle.")
  }
}

public func loadMyFonts() {
  loadFontWith(name: "ComicSansPro-Regular")
  loadFontWith(name: "ComicSansPro-Medium")
  loadFontWith(name: "ComicSansPro-Bold")
  loadFontWith(name: "ComicSansPro-ExtraBold")
}
```

I ended up requiring the `loadMyFonts` method to be called in the application's that use this framework's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate.swift`.

Comment: That's it. ps: don't forget to add fonts to copy bundle resources for them to be found by path for resource

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd share my answer as well. My project is set up like so:

- Main iOS App (Swift)

  - Dynamic Framework (Obj-C)

    - Fonts.bundle (a bundle with all the fonts inside)
    - UIFont categories
    - NSBundle categories
    - Other framework classes
  - App Classes (ViewControllers, Models, CoreData, etc...)

My goal was to be able to have the main app call a single method on the dynamic framework to load fonts without the need for altering the Info.plist or adding the font files/bundle to the main target.

```
@import CoreText;

@implementation NSBundle (Fonts)

+ (NSBundle *)fontsBundle {
    // The only way I could find to do this is to hard code the sub-path. Using pathForResource doesn't seem to find Fonts.bundle, nor its contents\
    // This way the host app doesn't need to copy Fonts.bundle
    NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Frameworks/<YourFrameworkName>.framework/Fonts.bundle"];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    if (bundle == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Warning: Fonts.bundle could not be loaded. Have you included it in your target?");
    }
    return bundle;
}

- (BOOL)loadFonts {

    NSArray<NSString *> *names = @[
        @"GothamRnd-Bold",
        @"GothamRnd-BoldItal",
        @"GothamRnd-Book",
        @"GothamRnd-BookItal",
        @"GothamRnd-Light",
        @"GothamRnd-LightItal",
        @"GothamRnd-MedItal",
        @"GothamRnd-Medium",
    ];

    __block NSInteger failCounter = 0;
    [names enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id _Nonnull name, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *_Nonnull stop) {
        NSString *fontPath = [self pathForResource:name ofType:@"otf"];
        NSData *inData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fontPath];
        CFErrorRef error;
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)inData);
        CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);

        if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to load font at path: %@", fontPath);
                failCounter++;
            }
            CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
            NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
            CFRelease(errorDescription);
        }
        CFRelease(font);
        CFRelease(provider);

    }];

    return failCounter == 0;
}

@end
```

The only bummer in this code is you have to hard code the path to the Fonts.bundle. I couldn't get any combination of NSBundle methods to locate the Fonts.bundle file automatically. For instance no methods like this would return a path:

```
NSString *pathToBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Fonts" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSString *pathToFont = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFont" ofType:@"ttf"];
```

Aside from the hard coding (which will never change), this is working for me well enough though. I can now skin all of my client apps easily.

Comment: I'm not understanding your "fontsBundle" method. What calls this?

Comment: Intended to be called like so: if([[NSBundle fontsBundle] loadFonts] == NO) { /*error*/}