# How to set custom font size in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, customization, custom-font

Hi I am using a custom fonts in my application. First of all I include the font in .plist the then I have tried to use font in these two way

> 1. [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FtraBk__1" size:9]];
> 2. UIFont *CustomFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FtraBk__1" size:9];
>
>    [lblTitle setFont:CustomFont];

But in the both cases font size in not working. I am using these custom fonts in `uitableviewcustomcell`. So how can I adjust custom font Height.

Comment: Make sure the name of the font is correct. Does it show up as the correct font, but you just can't adjust the size?

Comment: ya it is showing the correct font don't know why I cant adjust the font size...

Answer (score 0):

This is very interactive thinking to use custom Font in IPhone APP

This link have lot of idea bout Custom Font.

[Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)