# Unable to add certain fonts in an iphone app

Tags: ios, fonts

In my app i need to add two fonts:

Insight_screen_Regular-e  and Insight_screen_Bold-e

I have dragged and dropped them in the ttf formats to the Xcode project resources folder. In the application-info.plist file I have added the key "Fonts provided by application" to a new row and then added two items for added fonts.Then i built the project.

Yet i am unable to access these fonts from the xib files. What might be the reason. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to access the fonts? Are you using `UIFont`'s `fontWithName:size:` selector?

Comment: Also what do your "Fonts provided by application" values look like?

Comment: i am using the xcode interface builder. I am unable to see the Insight fonts in the fonts list.

Comment: From what I understand it won't be explicitly listed, although I've never done it through IB. Have you considered setting the font via code?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616101/463892).

You're probably not using the right string in `fontWithName:size:`. You need to use the *PostScript* name of the font in `fontWithName:size:`, which you can find by opening the font in Font Book on OS X, selecting the font, and pressing cmd+I.

Answer (score 0):

From .m File I am using custom font like this

```
btnPhotoLibrary.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hand Of Sean" size:18];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks i have done the same, but i m unable to see the same font in the nib