# Available Fonts on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, fonts

I am trying to make a `UILabel` in Swift -- the label will display a simplified Chinese character.   I am trying to use the Kaiti SC font that comes with the Mac, it is available in the Font Book and in all of the programs on the Mac, but when I list out the fonts using the following code, it does not show up.

```
    let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames()

    for familyName in fontFamilyNames {

        print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
        let names = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName)
        print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
    }
```

The code for my UILabel is as follows:

```
   let characterLabel:UILabel! = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(600,140,300,300));

   characterLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Kaiti SC" , size:250.0);

   characterLabel.text = "说";
```

I would have thought all of the fonts on the Mac would be available in my Swift program.   (The code, of course, does work with other fonts like "Baskerville", the Chinese characters simply don't look good in those fonts.)  Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10684202/1378447

Comment: Maybe it's just not available natively. Try adding it as custom font and then retry.

Comment: @LinusG. Be aware that you might need a distribution license for the font you want to include in your app. Since you are redistributing it.

Comment: @rckoenes, thanks, you are right.  I did just find this font list from Apple https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202771     It says that KaiTi does not come installed on the iPad, but is one of the additional fonts that is available.    So I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 7):

And here Swift 5 Version:

```
let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames

for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
    print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
    let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
    print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The font `Kaiti SC` is not available on iOS, for a full list of available font check http://iosfonts.com/

Although the font is available on OS X does not mean that it is available or fully available on iOS.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be the answer to my question.

If you go to https://support.apple.com/en-ap/HT202771, you will see what fonts are available in iOS.  In addition, it says "Apps can download the following fonts if necessary:" and these include a number of Asian and other fonts.  They do not tell you how to access those fonts.  Apparently, those fonts are on the Mac, and must be specifically downloaded to iOS.

This site shows you how to do that:  http://www.perfectline.co/blog/2010/05/uiappfonts-custom-fonts-with-the-iphoneipad-3-2-sdk/

The two tricks I found necessary: (1) you need to add a new key in info.plist and (2) you must write a function to list out the font families, so you know the actual font name you need to use in your program.   This site has such a function: http://giordanoscalzo.tumblr.com/post/95900320382/print-all-ios-fonts-in-swift

Comment: If that's the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted to let people know that an appropriate answer has been given, please.