# Added custom font to project but when I try and use them I get a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsattributedstring

I added a custom font to my project and made sure it was in the "Copy Bundle Resources" in Build Phases. I also made sure it was added properly to the plist file: [image: plist]

but when I set up a function for placeholder text :

```
let attributes = [
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
  NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "NeutraText-Bold", size: 17)!
]


func placeHolder(_ text: String) -> (NSAttributedString){
  return NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes:attributes)
}

   signUpTextField.attributedPlaceholder = placeHolder("Sign Up")
```

I get the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

for the line

```
  NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "NeutraText-Bold", size: 17)!
```

Comment: Could you print all the fonts name ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891959/available-fonts-on-ios It help to assure that your font is correctly added in the app, and also give the real name to use (which is in fact the postscript name of the font, which may be different from the "commercial one").

Comment: It doesn't appear in the list when printed out, any idea why that could be?

Comment: Check all the steps from there: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/ ?

Comment: You have to add your font to Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737788/custom-fonts-in-ios-7 should contain everything you have to check for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using folder reference to keep your fonts, you need to make sure that folder itself is assigned to your target.

[image]

If you case, mark the top folder you have, and on the right side, check if Target Membership is marked correctly.