# How can I see other options of Font that SwiftUI can offer as custom font?

Tags: swiftui

I am using a Text which I want use SwiftUI custom fonts that can be offered as custom font from Apple, but I do not know, how can I see those offers? I also tried in canvas, and I just could do some padding or Color change, I am trying to see the List of Fonts that SwiftUI offer to us as custom one.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .font(Font.custom("?", size: 20)) // <<: How can I know, what I can choose?
            
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

```
import SwiftUI


let customFonts: (allKinds: [String], allFonts: [String]) = allCustomFontsFinder()

func allCustomFontsFinder() -> (allKinds: [String], allFonts: [String]) {
    
    let allKinds: [String] = UIFont.familyNames.sorted()
    var allFonts: [String] = [String]()
    
    allKinds.forEach { familyItem in
        
        UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyItem).forEach { item in allFonts.append(item) }
        
    }
    
    return (allKinds: allKinds, allFonts: allFonts)
    
}







struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            
            ForEach(customFonts.allFonts, id: \.self) { item in
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text(item)
                        .font(Font.custom(item, size: 20))
                        .onTapGesture { print(item) }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: { let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general; pasteboard.string = item }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc")
                    })
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear() {
            
            print("count Of CustomFontKinds:", customFonts.allKinds.count)
            print("count Of AllCustomFonts:", customFonts.allFonts.count)
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to see them (visually) or access programmatically?

Comment: It would be nice both, but I need to know all what we can do

Comment: To show them visually is nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way to find all the fonts that are available is to list them in the console.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Show the fonts")
            .onAppear {
                for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
                    let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
                    print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

This will print out something like this (this is a shortened list, the actual list is much longer):

> Family: Academy Engraved LET Font names: ["AcademyEngravedLetPlain"]
>
> Family: Al Nile Font names: ["AlNile", "AlNile-Bold"]
>
> Family: American Typewriter Font names: ["AmericanTypewriter",
> "AmericanTypewriter-Light", "AmericanTypewriter-Semibold",
> "AmericanTypewriter-Bold", "AmericanTypewriter-Condensed",
> "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight",
> "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold"]
>
> Family: Apple Color Emoji Font names: ["AppleColorEmoji"]
>
> Family: Apple SD Gothic Neo Font names: ["AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular",
> "AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin", "AppleSDGothicNeo-UltraLight",
> "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light", "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium",
> "AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold", "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold"]
>
> Family: Apple Symbols Font names: ["AppleSymbols"]

The names inside the `[]` are the fonts that are available to you

Or you can do something like this to show the fonts in your view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(UIFont.familyNames.sorted(), id: \.self) { family in
                let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name).font(Font.custom(name, size: 20))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Programmatically

If you want to list all available fonts programmatically, you can use `UIFont.familyNames`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62256926/8697793) is an example:

```
let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames

for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
    print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
    let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
    print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
}
```

#### Visually

If you also want to *see* them, you can go to: http://iosfonts.com.

---

The ideal solution is to combine both these approaches: choose the font you like basing on its design etc, then list all available fonts to find its *real* name.