# Display klingon text on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, unicode

Is it possible to display Klingon text (it doesn't have to be editable) on iOS?

If yes, what's the recommended way?

Comment: Klingon is not part of Unicode.

Comment: It's always *possible*, even if you have to resort to having an image for each character and drawing them yourself.

Comment: Use the class UINerdFeatures. Other than that, cHao actually posted a valid answer. It's not even that much work, since some Font packages are available on the web. Look up how to add custom fonts to applications, there might be a guide for that somewhere.

Comment: @thundersteele: Would you believe it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somebody has come up with a ["standard" mapping of Klingon](http://www.evertype.com/standards/csur/klingon.html) to the private usage area of Unicode.  All you need to do is [find a font](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=klingon%20truetype%20font&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for Klingon (or use bitmaps) and away you go.  There will be [some work needed to install your font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application) onto the device.

Comment: And [here is](http://www.kasper-online.de/en/docs/startrek/klingon.htm) a ttf Klingon font