# Font file added to project, plist, code, and compile resources, but still not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiappfonts

I have followed the steps discussed in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application), but without success.

1. Added file `fontFile.ttf` to Xcode Project resources.
2. Added `fontFile.ttf` as a string in the UIAppFonts array in Info.plist.
3. Added `actualFontName` in the code.
4. Added file `fontFile.ttf` to target.

I have checked that I am using the actual font name as recognized by Font Book and Finder info (`CMD + i` in each). I have also double-checked the spelling and case-sensitivity of the included file name.

The code rendering the label works with other embedded system fonts, but not with the custom TTF. What else could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer: Check that the file is added to the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase

The problem was that I was adding the file to "Compile Sources" instead of "Copy Bundle Resources".

Thus, step 4 should read as follows:

*4. Add file fontFile.ttf to bundle resources of target*

To check that the file is in the right place, navigate to the Build Phases tab of the project, scroll down to "Copy Bundle Resources" and verify the file's presence. If not there, simply add it by clicking the corresponding "+" button.

**NOTE:** This whole situation can be avoided if you select the "Add to target" checkbox when first dragging the file into your project.

Comment: funny thing is I have them in Copy Bundle Resources. Xcode still isn't having it though.

Comment: @atreat : go check this, it might be relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873120/custom-fonts-are-working-on-simulator-but-not-rendering-in-some-storyboards/55873121#55873121