# Custom ttf font is not working in iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, ios, fonts, truetype

I added a new ttf font file in my app. I already added in the plist too. It's work on my device, but it is not working properly in some other devices. Can any one suggest me - how to do? Is there any other steps that i could follow to achieve this????

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have followed all the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application) to set up custom fonts. If you have a previous version of your app without font installed on the other device your font are now not working delete the app so you can ensure that all the resource bundle (with your new font) are correctly copied when building and running your app.