# iOS custom font issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

I am stuck in the following problem:
I have to use the following font: **Helvetica Neue LT Pro** . Medium condensed and Bold condensed styles.

I first had them as otf files and I read somewhere that it might be better to have them as **true-type** fonts. So I converted them to **.ttf** files using http://www.freefontconverter.com/

**What I did**:

1) I added the fonts in my **Resources bundle** , checked to be sure they are listed in `Copy Bundle Resources` section.

2) I added them in the `Fonts provided by application` entry in `Info.plist` with the complete name and extension of my 2 files : `helveticaneueltprobdcn.ttf` and `helveticaneueltpromdcn.ttf`

3) I used this code to check the fonts were installed and get the name:

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames])
            {
                NSLog(@"----------------");
                NSLog(@"FAMILY: %@", familyName);
                for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName])
                {
                    NSLog(@"  %@", fontName);
                }
            }
```

4) The fonts were listed there , like this:

```
 FAMILY: Helvetica Neue LT Pro
   HelveticaNeueLTPro-MdCn
   HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCn
```

5) Still not working when trying to use `[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCn" size:16]`. It's not the font that I asked for , I guess it does not find it and uses the system default. If I change the size , there's no change - I can use size 16 or 46 , the result is the same.

6) I tried deleting and re-installing the app  , clean project in XCode , everything I could think of.

Does anyone have any idea why this wouldn't work?
I googled a lot and I couldn't find a solution.
If it matters , I'm using **XCode 4.3.2** , iOS **SDK 5.1** and running on an iPad with iOS 5.1.1 installed.

Thank you.

Regards,

George

Comment: hi check out below link it might be helpful 

[click me :)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Comment: have a look to your font name in font book and use the same post script name: is it still shown as HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCn?

Comment: Forgot to mention , I did that already . It's the same name. This stuff makes me crazy , I used custom fonts many times , I can't find a reason for it not to work now.

Comment: Yes honestly there is nothing else i could think of. May be just try another custom font and see if it works.

Comment: I tried 2 other fonts , no luck there either.

Comment: You are using interface builder ? You can change the text by code ? If you change to a system font what happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it...

Here's what I was doing:

```
MyCustomView *view = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
//bla bla
```

In MyCustomView.m , in the init method I had this:

```
- (id) init
{
     //create some labels and set their fonts.
}
```

The problem is that at the time at which I was setting the font , the parent view of the labels ( MyCustomView instance ) was not added to a superview.

I made a `setFonts` method that I called after I called init on the MyCustomView instance and when I set the fonts there, it worked!

Hope this helps.

Cheers!