# Set my own font in my app iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

I'd like to put a text in my app with a special font but I don't know how to do it ?

Someone could explain me or have a link about it ?

Thanks

Comment: With one search here on stackoverflow I found this... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

There are many pages on the net describing how to do this.  http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/using-custom-fonts-in-your-ios-application/ is one of them.