# Change the Font of a the Label within UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uifont

I'm currently writing a database app via storyboards, and I'm right now I am in the stage of making it look fancy. I've added the font, `Gotham.ttf`, to the app with Info.plist. And yes, I did copy the font file into the project.

[image: Info.plist]

Within my `ViewController.m` I have the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // Cell Configuration
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [device valueForKey:@"name"], [device valueForKey:@"version"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"company"]];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham" size:20];
    
    return cell;
}
```

Everything works fine in the code. I know this because if I change Gotham to "Arial" or "Tahoma", the fonts come out fine when I launch the app. But when I try to change the font of the label to "Gotham", it just reverts to the default font used for a cell. I have definitely implemented the font wrong, I'm just not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: U don't have Gotham Font in the list of fonts that are provided by the apple.

Answer (score 0):

Please see details here:

[Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application/2616101#2616101)

Did you follow all the steps thoroughly?

Also, do you really have the file extension `tff`? It should be `ttf` for 'true type font'.

Comment: Alright I'll look into it, and what? The file is `ttf`, did you see the screenshot above?

Comment: You have made a typo above the screenshot... Wait... I corrected it :)

Comment: Yup, as Kashiv noted, you wrote tff in the text of your question, which is what I was querying.