# Attribute Line spacing not works - Xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, xib, nsattributedstring, custom-font

I set the attribute line spacing for UILabel in xib with custom font and then run the code. The label having line spacing but not with custom font instead its shown with System font I think. Even, the font size is also not same that is large than I set.

I know the code for applying the line spacing, custom font. However, In my app I have many static text. I want to apply some attribute properties for it without reference.

- OS X El Capitan, Xcode 7, Storyboard not followed
- Custom Font: Installed in Mac and added in plist too

Comment: show your code, please.

Comment: @johnelemans What code you want? Am trying in Xib. My objective is to avoid reference for labels and set line spacing with custom font.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read your question too quickly. I tried installing a font on my machine and then using it in a UILabel, but I can't even see the font in IB!  Here is a related post; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109047/added-custom-font-not-working-in-xcode

Comment: @johnelemans This is not my problem. My custom font is shown in app when the label is plain. Even i can use in attributes but not in case of line spacing through XIB!