# Is it possible to put custom fonts in Cocoa Touch Framework and use them in all projects?

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

I'm an Android developer and new in IOS. In Android, we have **aar** which we can put all common resources in it and use aar as a library in all project. I searched a lot( [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507905/xcode-using-custom-fonts-inside-dynamic-framework/32870919) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735522/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-a-bundle-and-access-it-from-an-ios-framework) [(3)](https://www.reddit.com/r/simpleios/comments/2oiptv/question_using_custom_fonts_in_cocoa_touch/) but couldn't find any similar solution in IOS. Should I write extension?

Comment: Using custom fonts require you to add entries into `Info.plist`. The closest thing in the iOS world is an [Xcode Template](https://medium.com/@dasdom/creating-a-smart-xcode-file-template-b5f2d7c8594b)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, you can create your custom font class and define all your custom fonts inside and you can reuse them across the project.