# Dotted font library for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am writing an app where I have to insert text in the form of dots, similar to that found on scoreboards. An example would be like

[image]

Is there an iOS open source library I can use to do this ?

Comment: Googling “scoreboard font” or “scoreboard text font” finds several fonts that might meet your needs.  Why not use one of them?  [Example](http://www.fontspace.com/category/scoreboard) [Example](http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/363872)

Comment: Related: [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2616101/457406)

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIFont to accomplish this easily using a .ttf font file:

http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635

This font might work for you:

http://www.dafont.com/score-board.font