# scoreboard fonts already in iOS?

Tags: ios, fonts

I'm writing an app and I'm thinking about using a font for the scores like the old dotted numbers from scoreboards. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800654/dotted-font-library-for-ios) question and answer from a few years ago and I was wondering if I would still need to embed the font into my app or if it has been added to the list of fonts already available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That font is not built-in.  You'll need to embed that custom font in your app.

[iOS Fonts](http://iosfonts.com) shows which fonts are bundled with (each version of) iOS.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but wanted to double check.