# custom font too small

Tags: ios, fonts

I'm trying to set a custom font and, following the last answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application) question, I seem to have the font working in the project.

The only trick is that it's always the same size - too small.  I'm trying to set it rather large but it's always small, no matter the size.  Here's the line of code I'm using, as per the instructions in the above link.

```
    self.timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DistProTh" size:48];
```

I know the line works because I can change the font name (DistProTh) to something another font (say, Didot) and everything's fine.  It therefore seems to me to be an issue with the [font](https://philsfonts.com/index.php/free_fonts) (which is freely available) but the font works ok in other applications (Stickies for example).  Sadly, I'm no font expert..

Comment: You are not setting `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to `YES`, do you?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Nope.  All I have to do is change the name of the font for it to work.

Comment: Have you added property for this font to plist file?

Comment: @PrateekPrem Yep, just like the instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 1):

The `fontName` parameter of the `fontWithName:` method is the full name of the font, not its file name. `DistProTh` is the file name; the full name of that font is `District Pro Thin`.

This should fix the problem:

```
self.timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"District Pro Thin" size:48];
```

Font name and file name are often the same, but that's not always the case. To look up the name of the font, locate your font in the Font Book application, and press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to view font's information.

Comment: Hmm.  Didn't do the trick.  I wonder if there's a way for fonts to know that they're going to be on a mobile device and stop working.  I say that because I was trying another 'free' font and saw this page - note the categories & prices: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/font-fabric/code-pro/buy.html

Comment: I got another free font working.  One called "CODE Light".  I wonder if there isn't an issue with "District Pro Thin".

Comment: @arigold I was about to mention the postscript name, which has been mentioned in [this highly upvoted comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application#comment12465682_2616101) to one of the answers to the question that you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it needed what Font Book calls the "PostScript name" which, in the case of District Pro Thin is `DistrictPro-Thin`.

Incidentally, either the "PostScript name" or the "full name" (as per Font Book) worked for the font called "Code Light" but not for "District Pro Thin".