# MS Reference Sans Serif, iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on app for a client, the client wants all text in font MS Reference Sans Serif, which is a microsoft font, how can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to purchase the font http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1273

Once you have the TTF, follow steps specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616101/1029360

Comment: Thanks, thats what I wanted to know.