# Can not connect and use custom font in iOS app

Tags: ios

I download this font: http://www.alliphonefont.com/iphone-ipad-font/Neucha/146
but can not connect it. I add this file in project, add to the plist, copy Bundle Resources, but can't see it in list of available fonts in log. Help me pleas!

Comment: The file your downloading is not the font file but a package intended to be used with a Jailbroken device. The intent is to overwrite the system fonts with the custom font. To use within your project you should find the actual font and include that way. And that has been answered on SO before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

Use to load the font:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"POSTSCRIPT NAME OF FONT" size:12];
```

You can get the postscript name by doing get info in FontBook.