# sizeWithFont Is always returning 0

Tags: ios, uitableview, sizewithfont

I'm trying to dynamically determine the size each row should be in in table view using sizeWithFont, but it's always 0.0 for some reason. Here is my code:

```
    - (CGFloat)labelHeight:(NSString *)text {
        CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINCond-Medium" size:14]
                                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(218, 100000)
                                        lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        NSLog(@"Height: %1f", expectedLabelSize.height);

        return expectedLabelSize.height;
    }
```

I'm not sure why it would return 0 ever.

Any help would be wunderbar. Thanks.

Comment: is that font available?

Comment: Split the code up. `UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DINCond-Medium" size:14];`. Then you can check if `font` is `nil` or not. Also verify that `text.length > 0` (this includes making sure it isn't `nil`).

Comment: Have you specified fonts in your app's info.plist file? If you not, you need to set a following property "Fonts provided by application".

Comment: Thanks everyone, that font was indeed missing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `[text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINCond-Medium" size:14]` returns `nil` in your case, because the font can't be found. Make sure to use the font's proper name and also specify it in the Info.plist.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application/2616101#2616101) for a more detailed description.

Comment: Thank you! The font was missing.