# Custom fonts in IOS showing on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts

I've added custom fonts to my xcode project and they show up just fine when I run the app in the simulator but when I run it on my iPhone they don't show up. This is the code in my AppDelegate.m file

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[UIColor colorWithRed:23.0/255.0 green:97.0/255.0 blue:115.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lily Script One" size:23.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];
```

Comment: The first step would be to check if `[UIFont fontWithName:...]` returns `nil` or not ...

Comment: Make sure you've actually included the font in the bundle and added the required .plist entry. The simulator has more fonts available than the device since the simulator is actually OSX. [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3198821/168493)

Comment: most likely you forgot to check "copy items into destination groups folder" try re-importing the font and making sure to check that off

Comment: @ben that's exactly what happened, thanks for the help!

Comment: @BrandonHoulihan I do it all the time and the errors never make sense.  Always the first thing I check now