# Xcode : How To Customize Text Field Font With My Own TTF Font?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a simple question :

how to add / import my TTF font into Xcode so that it can be seen on 'Attributes Inspector' custom font list, so that it can be used on any components (text field, button, label, etc).

thank you.

Comment: Hope this will help you  [Custom Font](http://stackoverflow.com/q/360751/2407907)

Answer (score 1):

Id be surprised if there was a way to get a custom font to show up in IB. The standard way is to include the font names in your plist (and the ttf files in your project) and then they are available using `[UIFont fontWithName:size:]`

You'll likely have to loop through all available font names (using the class methods on UIFont) to get the exact string to use for the name parameter.

Save for your asking about having them show up in IB, this question is a duplicate: [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)