# How to use Bold font in iOS for mixed languages?

Tags: ios, uifont, bold

I know we can use **boldSystemFontOfSize**, but I want to use another font such as Arial, yes, we can use **[UIFont fontWithName:"Arial-Bold"...]** to get English chars to **Bold**, the problem is, other chars such as east Asian chars are not Bold, because Arial-Bold only supports western chars and for non-western chars, it will use system default one which is not Bold. Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Use a different font o,0.  One that supports all of the Unicode sets that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Find a font that supports bold non-western characters. Include it in your project, and make sure you add the font to your .plist with the `Fonts provided by application` key. Then use `fontWithFontName` to load it.

EDIT

So, the question is: have you tried any other iOS-native fonts? I don't know if any of the iOS-supplied fonts have what you want.

For a list of fonts, by iOS version, check here: http://iosfonts.com/

If you want to see those on the device and see if they support your desired character sets, modify one of these projects and see if any of the fonts you like work for you:

https://github.com/ekurutepe/iOS-Font-Gallery

https://github.com/ElfSundae/iOSFontList

If you don't find a font you like, you'll need to look for a font, not included in iOS and include that in your project. There are plenty out there for free. Google "free fonts" to get started.

If you find a font you like, include it as above. Here's a link to one of many SO questions that gives the steps:

[Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application/2616101#2616101)

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I'll not ask here if this is a solution, :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I'm using a custom font now, I said "Arial-Bold" just for an example...