# iphone apps font change doesn't look like it should

Tags: iphone, fonts

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941850/custom-fonts-in-xcode-5) how to code the font exchange, I have two following questions,

1)why the actual font looks different from what it should look like

2)do i have to first install the fonts on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using system fonts then its ok.

But to use custom fonts which are not provided by xcode then refer this

[How to include and use new fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

EDIT:

To check fonts are added properly or not call this function and check names of fonts properly

```
-(void)checkFontList
{
    NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
    NSArray *fontNames;
    NSInteger family, font;
    for (family=0; family<[familyNames count]; ++family)
    {
        NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:family]);
        fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[familyNames objectAtIndex:family]]];

        for (font=0; font<[fontNames count]; ++font)
        {
            NSLog(@" Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:font]);
        }
        [fontNames release];
    }
    [familyNames release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly what i did and the font changes but not to what it should look like