# custom font with attached font (iLaplas.ttf)

Tags: iphone, xcode, fonts

i want to use custom font in my ios project;
i have not problem with other fonts but with this font: http://modireaval.com/iLaplas.ttf
please help me.
thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean with other fonts? Other custom fonts?

Comment: Yes, custom fonts...?

Comment: Well, other fonts than the one you can access in InterfaceBuilder. One you import yourself. If you see the answer of Jordan Montel, did you do theses steps?

Answer (score 0):

How do you use this font ?

**To use custom font :**

1/ add your custom font in your project like resources (font .ttf or .otf)

2/ in your info.plist add key UIAppFonts (Fonts provided by application) and and the name of each custom font (for example : iLaplas.ttf)

3/ you can create macro for use your font

```
#define FONT_ILAPLAS_STD(s) [UIFont fontWithName:@"iLaplas" size:s]
```

4/ use this macro for a label par exemple :

```
_myLabel.font = FONT_ILAPLAS_STD(15.0f);
```

Have a look to the different answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941850/custom-fonts-in-xcode-5).