# objective-c changing UILabel's font not work

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uifont

i want to change my label's font using below code:

```
UILabel *lblBolge = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 38)];
lblBolge.text=@"Bölge";
lblBolge.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"CarterOne" size:10];
```

but still i see system font and default size

any reason?

Comment: you did not add the font to your project correctly. there may be several things that you could do wrong. The process of adding a font has been covered multiple times here. Google it

Comment: Where do you actually add it to its superview? Are you sure you didn't get confused with the object declared in interface builder and the newly allocated object in your code?

Comment: in viewdidLoad function

Answer (score 1):

Carter font is not part of the iOS SDK. To add a custom font you need to get hold of the .ttf or .otf file of the font and add it to your project. Here's a [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application) on how to do that.