# How to apply FS Elliot font in a uiLabel xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

Can anyone direct me on how to change/apply a `font:FS Elliot on a UILabel`. I have been searching Google and found none. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

01 Add your ttf font file to the Xcode project under resources.

02 Add array in the info.plist with the key UIAppFonts and every font you want to added to it.

03 Call [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFontName" size:15] from everywhere you need