# iOS unknown delay between animationControllerForPresentedController and animateTransition

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, transition

I'm having an annoying issue with a custom transition using UIViewControllerContextTransitioning when triggering the animation from a tableView

I followed many tutorials out there, to name a few :
 - http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/ios-7-custom-view-controller-transitions-and-rotation-making-it-all-work
 - http://objectivetoast.com/2014/03/17/custom-transitions-on-ios/

This is the exact problem I have (but no solution :/ ): [Custom transition animation unknown delay between animationControllerForPresentedController and animateTransition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396898/custom-transition-animation-unknown-delay-between-animationcontrollerforpresente)
Sometimes it works, sometimes it's just to slow.

I don't know what happens behind the scenes between animationControllerForPresentedController and animateTransition. If you have an idea on how to debug that I'd like to hear it.

Comment: 1) show us your code. 2) even without seeing your code I'm pretty sure you having a main thread issue. (see http://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks#mainthread - understand that, both about not blocking the main thread and always doing UI on the main thread.)

Comment: Problem solved. didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called from the main thread (I always assumed it was the case). I just had to wrap my code inside a dispatch call. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it work, I've made my comment into an answer, so if you accept it I'll get some magic internet points. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without seeing your code I'm pretty sure you having a main thread issue. (see http://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks#mainthread - understand that, both about not blocking the main thread and always doing UI on the main thread.