# UITextView fix character width

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, uifont

My problem is that I have to two `UITextView` displaying different Text, but always the same number of characters. I could not find a way to set a fix character-width and space width in `UITextView/NSAtrrStr/UIFont`.
Is there a way to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `Courier New` is the only fixed-width font shipped with iOS.

Also, you can always import custom fonts to your xcode project which you know are fixed-width. Here is how: [Embed Custom Font in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616101/874886)