# Use custom font in swift

Tags: swift, fonts

I need a font for swift sprite kit, iOS.
this font is for commercial purposes and im trying to have a kind of arcade font. I would want to create my own font, or to get a public font which i can use for commercial purposes, and how do I install this font, how do I implement it on swift. Thank you.

Comment: I know the question has been answered, but I would like to share this resource with you. Make sure the font you use is permitted for commercial use in the license: http://www.dafont.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Custom Fonts Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420758/swift-custom-fonts-xcode-7)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Fist make sure that your font is .ttf or .otf format

1. Import your font into the project
2. Add new key "Fonts provided by application" on application's info.plist file and add your font names
   Now you can use custom fonts with interface builder or programatically

[image]

```
yourLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: YourFont, size: size)
```

Comment: Can you add instructions on how to programmatically set the newly added font.

Comment: @3366784, I have updated it for programmatically.

Answer (score 17):

1. First of all you need to drag the font into the project.
2. After that you need to select the font and select the target Membership checkmark for your app as seen in the picture.

[image: Xcode window with selected target membership for the custom font]

3. After that you go to your Info.plist and add the Name of the font in "Fonts Provided By Application"
4. Now you can finally use the font als you would use every other font. If it doesn't work as ir should you can find out the name Xcode gave the font with

   ```
   for name in UIFont.familyNames() {
     println(name)
     if let nameString = name as? String

   {

       println(UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(nameString))
     }
   }
   ```

> #### UPDATE
>
> The Font is called Fipps-Regular and 100% free to use [Download here](http://dl.dafont.com/dl/?f=fipps)

Comment: Thank you the font is awesome but the explanation on how to use it is not

Comment: I get it :D no problem

Answer (score 2):

i would like to add this code 
if you know your font family name (which you can see in the fontPicker in the IterfaceBuilder) 
use this to apply the font programatically

```
func apply_font(FontFamilyName:String)
{
  label.font = UIFont(name: UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: 
  **FontFamilyName**)[0], size: 15)
}
```