# How to use custom font in a tvOS project using SwiftUI?

Tags: fonts, swiftui, tvos, custom-font

I made an App for iOS and MacOS and I am now working on the tvOS version.
The issue I am facing is that the custom font is not working when I use the following code for tvOS!

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
      Text("R")
      .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 160))
      .bold()
      .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 15, x: 15, y: 5)
      .foregroundColor(Color(red: 255 / 255.0, green: 194 / 255.0, blue: 58 / 255.0))
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

The wrong result with the above code is the below letter:

[image: Wrong Letter]

The good letter that should be displayed by the above code should look like the one below:

[image: Good letter I want to writte]

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that works for iOS & macOS but doesn't work for tvOS. Maybe because there are different built-in fonts available for iOS and tvOS? I don't have expertise in tvOS, so please don't assume I'm right. I'm guessing it from this available font list.

**tvOS:**
Try something from this list, and I'm sure it'll work.

[image]

**iOS:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Finally I used the font called "Courier" found in your list you forward me. This is the font that is the closest from the rounded letter I wanted. It is a pitty that I could not use the same font I used on iOS and MacOS.

Comment: @Wild8x If you want to keep fonts the same on all platforms, I prefer you import something your own. For that, I recommend these two [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060384/use-custom-font-in-swift) | [SwiftUI](https://medium.com/better-programming/swiftui-basics-importing-custom-fonts-b6396d17424d). Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi @Luffy, finally I managed to found the missing fonts on 'cufonfonts.com' and I followed the tutorial you pointed to me... It works fine! Thanks again.

Comment: @Wild8x glad to hear that :)