# How to reference a San Francisco font in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, fonts, swift2

If we want to reference a font usually we will be using,

Font:  `For Ex. let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue",size :14)`

In case of using, San Francisco font, I wasn't able to reference the font the same way,

```
 let font = UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Semibold",size :14)
```

Instead, I have to reference like this,

```
 let font = UIFont(name: ".SFUIText-Semibold",size:14)
```

What is the difference between the both? and how come using a ".(dot)" operator before the font name reference to SF Font.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Custom Fonts Xcode 7.0 Beta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420758/swift-custom-fonts-xcode-7-0-beta)

Comment: There is no duplicate, I have exactly used the custom font as detailed in above link. But when I try to set the font using 'titleTextAttributes' in UINavigationBar, I wasn't able to load the font   
 
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name :"SFUIText-Semibold" ,size :14)]

The font doesn't gets loaded.

Comment: Can you post the complete code, how you are setting it to `UINavigationBar`

Comment: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name :"SFUIText-Semibold" ,size :14)]

Answer (score 0):

I can reference using this below line to my `UILabel`:

```
lblTitle.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Event", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name :".SFUIText-Semibold", size :14)!])

lblTitle.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Event", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name :"SFUIText-Semibold", size :14)!])
```

> What Have I Done?

I just drag and drop the font named `SF-UI-Text-Semibold.otf` to my project and make sure you have selected the project for reference.

Then, I added `SF-UI-Text-Semibold.otf` to `info.plist` under `Fonts provided by application`.

Finally, I can used the font anywhere!

Comment: What is project for reference?

Comment: means when you drag and drop, you must select the current project to include it!

Comment: Yes, I have done it already. It works fine for UILabel. If you want the change the font(Custom font) of UINavigationBar Title. It does not works.