# Adobe Fonts in XCode projects

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, adobe

Is it possible to use Adobe Fonts in an XCode project?
Actually, I know how to add custom fonts, but the Adobe fonts are not locally installed into the macOS font folder, it is managed by an Adobe tool.
If anybody knows a way, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift Custom Fonts Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420758/swift-custom-fonts-xcode)

Comment: You can only use a custom font if you have the font file itself. And, you must have the **rights** to use/distribute that font. It sounds like the "Adobe Fonts" you're asking about are the ones provided as part of the Creative Cloud subscription, and thus are only available with Creative Cloud software.

Comment: If you want to distribute an app with fonts, you need a license for the fonts that permits that. The Adobe Fonts service doesn't support that scenario, but all of the fonts available in Adobe Fonts can be obtained from other vendors. All Adobe Original fonts, such as Myriad Pro, can be licensed for use in apps from FontSpring -- see https://www.fontspring.com/worry-free for their license details.