# Custom fonts not working on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uifont

I had applied custom font to my application which works fine for iphone6 plus and iphone 5s but while running it on iOS 7 default fonts gets loaded,

Comment: I hope you know how to ask a good question:-http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Comment: the question is simple , custom fonts are not working on iOS 7. What might be the problem

Comment: I know how to load a custom font @fahriAzimov  and all about plist configuration and resource packages